# Twitter Streaming Filter API: Not seeing tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm dabbling with the twitter streaming filter API (https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter). I have two twitter accounts. One account I'm using for the API calls, the other is my personal account which I'm using for testing. In the API call, I'm using the "follow" parameter to follow the tweets of many users (like 50), including my personal account. However, when i publish a tweet from my personal account, sometimes i see the tweets and sometimes i don't. For the two tests tweets I sent, they arrived long after the tweet was sent, maybe 5 minutes or so (slow for streaming standards).

My question is, how does this API endpoint work? Does it guarantee delivery of all tweets for users you're following or is it only a sample of the tweets? And if it does guarantee delivery, why is it so slow? Does it only deliver tweets that have arrived after the time the stream connection is made?

Thank you

---

Comment: That's a difficult question. In some cases twitter explicitly says "returns only a sample", e.g. [GET statuses/sample](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample), but I guess it does not mean in the other cases the delivery is guaranteed (or fast). It is a public service. Anyway, you could try [user streams](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams) or the rest api, e.g. [GET statuses/timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline), I think you'll have more chances. It depends on what you are trying to do, of course.

Comment: @lrnzcig , whats odd is that when you review the documentation for the filter, it doesnt say "sample". only says this in the overview of the public stream docs. using the user stream will eventually be limiting in that it only returns "my" stream containing tweets of only users I follow. When i get past needing to see tweets from over 2000 accounts, this will not work. Using site streams. using the rest api's will also be limiting when i need to track tweets of a large amount of accounts in that i'll easily exceed the rate limitations. Perhaps when that time comes, i'll need the firehose.

Comment: agreed it does not say "sample". Anyhow, maybe I should rephrase: only thing that I can say with *certainty* (meaning "in my experience") is that the REST api tends to get more tweets than the Public streaming api. I probably should have mentioned that I haven't used user streams yet (could live with rest api rate limits).